# Rows to multiple columns transformation in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe like this:

| A | B | C |
| --- | --- | --- |
| One | 12 | 13 |
| One | 10 | 9 |
| One | 3 | 6 |
| Two | 11 | 7 |
| Two | 14 | 12 |
| Three | 12 | 8 |
| Three | 1 | 9 |
| Three | 3 | 4 |

I need to transform the dataframe as this:

| A | B | C | B2 | C2 | B3 | C3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| One | 12 | 13 | 10 | 9 | 3 | 6 |
| Two | 11 | 7 | 14 | 12 |  |  |
| Three | 12 | 8 | 1 | 9 | 3 | 4 |

I would be very grateful if you could help me.

Thank you

Answer (score 2):

### `groupby` with `cumcount`

```
df.set_index(['A', df.groupby('A').cumcount()]).unstack()

          B                C           
          0     1    2     0     1    2
A                                      
One    12.0  10.0  3.0  13.0   9.0  6.0
Three  12.0   1.0  3.0   8.0   9.0  4.0
Two    11.0  14.0  NaN   7.0  12.0  NaN
```

---

Nailing down actual desired output

```
d0 = df.set_index(['A', df.groupby('A').cumcount()]).unstack()
d0.columns = [f'{tup[0]}{"" if tup[1] == 0 else tup[1]}' for tup in d0.columns]
d0.reset_index()

       A     B    B1   B2     C    C1   C2
0    One  12.0  10.0  3.0  13.0   9.0  6.0
1  Three  12.0   1.0  3.0   8.0   9.0  4.0
2    Two  11.0  14.0  NaN   7.0  12.0  NaN
```

Comment: This is so neat! :)

Answer (score 1):

Try with `stack` and `pivot`:

```
stacked = df.set_index("A").stack().reset_index()
stacked["Column"] = stacked["level_1"].add(stacked.groupby(["A","level_1"]).cumcount().add(1).astype(str))
output = stacked.pivot("A","Column",0).rename_axis(None,axis=1)

>>> output
         B1    B2   B3    C1    C2   C3
A                                      
One    12.0  10.0  3.0  13.0   9.0  6.0
Three  12.0   1.0  3.0   8.0   9.0  4.0
Two    11.0  14.0  NaN   7.0  12.0  NaN
```

###### Input df:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'A': ['One', 'One', 'One', 'Two', 'Two', 'Three', 'Three', 'Three'],
                   'B': [12, 10, 3, 11, 14, 12, 1, 3],
                   'C': [13, 9, 6, 7, 12, 8, 9, 4]})
```